# Solutions of wave equation in area

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Prove that the solution for the wave equation in $\Omega = \mathbb{R} \times [0, \infty)$

$$u(x,0)=\begin{cases}
 1 & x \in (-\infty,-1) \\
 0 & x \in (-1,\infty)
\end{cases}
$$

is $u=0$ in the area $B=\{(x,t) | t \geq0,x-t \geq -1, x+t \leq 1\}$ but $u \neq 0$ outside of this area, i.e. $\{(x,t)|t \geq 0, t = 1 - x + \epsilon \lor t=x+1+ \epsilon\}, \epsilon > 0$.

For the first part I concluded that if $t \geq 0,x-t \geq -1, x+t \leq 1$ this means that $t=0,x=1$. So $u(x,0)=F(x)+G(x)=0$ (general solution of the wave equation). The $= 0$ is because $x \in (-1, \infty)$. This implies that $u(x,t)=F(x+t)+G(x-t)=F(x)+G(x)=0$ hence the first part is proven.

Is that correct? And how would I prove the second part?

Comment: The meaning of $$u(x,0)=\{1, x \in (-\infty,1)\\u(x,0) =\{0,x \in (-1,\infty)$$ is not clear. If these equations are supposed to represent boundary conditions, then the first seems to imply that $\ u(x,0)=1\ $ for $\ -1<x<1\ $, while the second seems to imply that $\ u(x,0)=0\ $ for $\ -1<x<1\ $, which is not consistent with the first.

Comment: Sorry, it should have been -1 in the first one. I made an edit.

Comment: Use the [cases environment](https://latex-programming.fandom.com/wiki/Cases_(LaTeX_environment)) to make the initial condition more clear.

Comment: Made another edit!